# IntelliJ ignores SIGINT when starting from start menu

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I'm starting IntelliJ under Linux Bionic 18.04 from the start menu I recognize following error:

"The IDE ignores SIGINT: the "Stop" button in run configurations may not work."

This error is already known but not seen as a bug on the Jetbrains side:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004770440

The effect is, when you are running an application and clicking some time the stop button that this has no effect.

IntelliJ Version is 2019.1.2. (problem appears also in versions from 2018)

This error is recognized by many people but there is no applicable workaround. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using MXLinux having an xfce desktop.
I get the SIGINT error message, when I start AndroidStudio from a launcher within the DockbarX panel-plugin, but not when I start it from the app-menu or a regular launcher in the panel.

Comment: I'm now on 19.2 and the problem disappeared.